# Plotting a complicated function

Tags: plotting, graphics, calculus-and-analysis

I have written a code and found 4 functions of k called s1i, s2i,s1r and s2r. I want to plot them in the same plot. I used Plot to plot them but there was no answer. how can I do it? Below is the code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Plot[s1i, k]
```

any answers re highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a *minimal* working example. What do you get if you post `s1i`?

Comment: You write `k = kk;` but `kk` has no earlier value.

Comment: The definition of `dp` starts off `dp = (x (v I\kk/2...1` What is the `\\` supposed to be? As is, it is generating a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
kt = 1;
(* ... *)
sha = Solve[Det[matt] == 0, s];
```

From this point on, my code:

```
Clear[s1, s2]
{s1[kk_], s2[kk_]} = sha[[All, 1, 2]];

Plot[Re[s1[u]], {u, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plotR1]

```
Plot[Im[s1[u]], {u, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plotI1]

```
Plot[Re[s2[u]], {u, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plotR2]

```
Plot[Im[s2[u]], {u, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plotI2]